# Why the std::map storing fewer elements than expected?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, stdmap, std

Why the map in my code is storing only two elements instead of three?

```
vector<int> v1 = { 140,229,319 };
vector<int> v2 = { 82,216,326 };
map<int, int> mp;

for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
{
    if (v1[i] > v2[i])
    {
        mp.insert({ 1,v1[i] - v2[i] });
    }
    else if (v2[i] > v1[i])
    {
        mp.insert({ 2,v2[i] - v1[i] });
    }
}

cout << mp.size() << endl;

for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++)
{
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
```

It should store: `(1,58) (1,13) (2,7)`ideally. But it is storing only `(1,58) (2,7)`. I checked the size and it was showing `2`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) has **unique** key. You might want [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Comment: Or you may want [`std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to keep the order.

Comment: Your map has two unique keys:  `1` and `2`.  What do you expect the third key to be?

Comment: @Jarod42 I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)is a sorted associative container, which only keeps unique keys. Meaning, what you're expecting is not possible with the `std::map`.

You should think either with

- [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)(sorted list of key-value pairs),
- [`std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)(unsorted list of key-value pairs) etc here, so that the multiple keys should not be an issue.

---

> Where am I going wrong?

Consider the check

```
if(v1[i] > v2[i])
```

you have two iteration which satisfy this condition:

```
140, 229   // v1
82 , 216   // v2
```

The difference (i.e. `v1[index] - v2[index]`) between the first two is `58` and the second is `13`.
In the first iteration, the map get inserted with the `(1, 58)`. In the second iteration it  should have `(1, 13)`, but from [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't**
> **already contain an element with an equivalent key**.

Hence it has not been inserted.